# SQL Running total with reset

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with dates and transactions. I need to calculate running total (which would be easy with sum partition by) except it needs to reset to zero when there is negative value in "amount" and then start calculating running total again. Any ideas?

```
account|amount|     date          |total|
123456 |50    |2017-01-01 00:00:00|50
123456 |50    |2017-01-02 00:00:00|100
123456 |100   |2017-01-03 00:00:00|200
123456 |-50   |2017-01-04 00:00:00|0
123456 |100   |2017-01-05 00:00:00|100
123456 |100   |2017-01-06 00:00:00|200
```

Comment: Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22235959/window-functions-running-total-with-reset?rq=1

Comment: No he saying he wants to restart the sum from 0 if a row with a negative is encountered

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With update variable method you can calculate running total with reset option.

```
declare @tblItems table(
 ID int identity(1, 1),
 Amount decimal(12, 3),
 RunningTotal decimal(12, 3) default(0)
)

insert into @tblItems(Amount)
values
 (50),
 (20),
 (-100),
 (5),
 (10)
;

DECLARE @RunningTotal decimal(12, 3) = 0;

UPDATE @tblItems
SET @RunningTotal = RunningTotal = case when amount<0 then 0 else (@RunningTotal + Amount) end
FROM @tblItems;

SELECT ID, Amount, RunningTotal
FROM @tblItems
ORDER BY ID;
```

Comment: Your solution assumes that the database system process the row in the order you inserted them in. Is it always true?

Comment: Yes agreed, that may be the case. But normally, running totals are often used in reports, and I think for reporting purpose usually don't have huge data tables. Like I did in many reports, first extracted data for reports in temp table (which of-course will not be huge one) with order by clause. Then this is a straight forward job.

Comment: I found nice article dealing with ordering using clustered index: https://sqlsunday.com/2014/06/29/inline-variable-assignment-in-update/